# What is the best way to change the cursor in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, cursor

I am new to JQuery.
I am trying to add some code in my HTML web page to change the cursor, 
but I am not sure if it is the best way to do it using JQuery alone rather than doing some self-custom declaration in an external CSS.
(I don't know if JQuery has got some built-in CSS properties.)

Here is the code for my very simple HTML web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#replybox").draggable();         
         $("#closed").mouseover(function(){
         $("#closed").css("cursor","pointer"); 
         });        
 });
</script>
<div id="replybox">
<form>
<table border="2">
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#FFAAAA">
<span id="closed">Press here to close this box</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
Content:<textarea name="data[Reply][quote]" id="data[Reply][quote]" cols="72" rows="18">Helloworld</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Please advise.

Comment: Forget JQuery.  You want CometCursor. ::ducks::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in CSS as well:

```
span.crosshair {cursor:crosshair}
span.help {cursor:help}
span.wait {cursor:wait}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not `$("#closed").css("cursor", "pointer");` outside of the `mouseover`? By default the cursor will only display when the mouse is over the element.

However, if you know from the start the element `#closed` will have a pointer cursor, why not put it in a style sheet? Something like `#closed { cursor: pointer; }`. This will let it work for people with JavaScript disabled too.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#closed").css("cursor", "property-value");`

see a list of available property-values here: http://w3schools.com/css/pr_class_cursor.asp